# deleting any list deletes the entire data from todo app

Tags: reactjs

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  const [director, setDirector] = useState();
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      movie: "",
      director: ""
    }
  ]);

  const handler = () => {
    setList([
      ...list,
      {
        movie: movie,
        director: director
      }
    ]);
    setDirector("");
    setMovie("");
  };
  const removeHandler = (del, index) => {
    const newList = list.filter((item) => {
     return item.movie !== del;
    });
   
    setList([newList]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App flex justify-between">
      <div>
        <input value={movie} onChange={(e) => setMovie(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
        <input value={director} onChange={(e) => setDirector(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <button style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} onClick={handler}>
        ADD
      </button>
      <div>
        {list?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li key={item.movie}>
                  {item.movie}, {item.director}
                  <button onClick={() => removeHandler(item.movie)}>
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
        }) || []}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using the filter to filter out the deleted list but it deletes the entire list on Click of remove button here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-feather-esbynl?file=/src/App.js:0-1423

Also the first list automatically generate without onSubmit

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple logical errors in the list removal logic. Try the below code.

```
  const removeHandler = (item, index) => {
    const newList = list.filter((list) => {
      return item !== list.movie;
    });

    setList(newList);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-paper-cq0ce7?file=/src/App.js:1025-1300

Remove the brackets from `setList([newList])`

```
setList(newList);
```

As a suggestion: `splice` is meant for deleting an item from an array

```
  const removeHandler = (index) => {
    setList((prev) => {
      const next = [...prev];
      next.splice(index, 1);
      return next;
    });
  };
```

```
<ul>
    {list.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={item.movie}>
          {item.movie}, {item.director}
          <button onClick={() => removeHandler(index)}>Remove</button>
        </li>
      );
    })}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this :

```
const removeHandler = (del, index) => {
     const newList = list.filter((item) => {
        return item.movie !== del;
     });
     setList(newList);
};
```

The "newList" will return a new array without the one that has the same "movie" with the one you pass as parameter.